# Cannot remove audio from video in FFMPEG (-an or -map doesnt work)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-encoding, h.264

### **the following dont work**

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -an <output>.mp4

ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0:0 -v:c copy <output>
```

The output returns the converted video WITH the audio still included. I'm trying to remove it.

---

**Input video info**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:28.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 858 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt709/bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 717 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: Share full logs.

Comment: I try your command and it's working for me.

Comment: download the latest version of FFmpeg and then try it. I think it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v copy -an <output>
```

Make a complete map, and then put the code for every of "-map".

The demostration: I create a video with the same especifications as in your question...

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4
```

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c copy -an video_cdpp.mp4
```

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i video_cdpp.p4
```

[image]

… and remember to specify all paramets for any "-map stream", if you want have to copy to new file, some important examples:

```
-an *if yuo don't want to copy "-map type audio"*
-vn *for not copying video*
-sn *for not copying subtitle*
-map_metadata -1 *for not  copying complete metadata*
```